# как преобразовать строку в число на реакте?

Tags: reactjs

Я  умножал цену товара на количество выбранных товаров и в итоге должно было выйти общая сумма выбранных товаров.

```
        <h1>Общая сумма</h1>
              <div>
             {cartItem.size?.map(cartItem=> <h1>{cartItem.price * cartItem.cartQuantity }</h1>)}
             {cartItem.price * cartItem.cartQuantity}
              </div>
```

Оказалось что ***price*** не number а string , как преобразавать в number или получить общую сумму?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией Number: ```Number(cartItem.price)```.

Comment: ```{cartItem.size?.map(cartItem => <h1>{Number(cartItem.price) * cartItem.cartQuantity }``` так?

Comment: Если в строке только цифры, то всё должно работать и без явного приведения. Например в JS `'5' * "5" = 25`. Лучше покажите что там за строка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: 1) +price либо 2) Number(price) https://learn.javascript.ru/type-conversions